# Reading a live log file from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using following code to read data from a text log file which is continually growing.

```
setInterval(call, 1000);

function call() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GenNumber.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      readdata(data);
    },
  });
}
```

My query is , does ajax reads complete file in every call or the (new) added lines from last call. If it reads entire file in each call, it may crash when file size bigger and bigger. Is there any way to read only new lines from the last call and stop the program when file stops growing.

Thanks

Comment: CODE=> setInterval(call,1000); 
function call(){
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GenNumber.txt",
        dataType: "text",
  success: function (data) { 
       readdata(data);
      },
 }); 
}

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35451918/edit) your question do not use comment to provide additional information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `headers` parameter for the `settings` parameter to the [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)() function to set a `Range` HTTP header to limit what data you are receiving.

Some examples:

```
bytes=9500-
```

will start sending data at offset 9500.

```
bytes=-500
```

will send the last 500 bytes.
This requires that the HTTP server supports ranges (most do).

The Range header is documented in [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

Taking your example code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "GenNumber.txt", 
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function (data) { readdata(data); }, 
        headers: {
            "Range" : "bytes=-500"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In complement to the neuhaus answer, using the `Range` header, you can store from the client side the total bytes already read.
So at each request, you will receive only data appended since the last call.

```
var byteRead=0;
setInterval(function(){

   $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "GenNumber.txt",
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function (data) {  
            byteRead+= data.length;
            readdata(data);
        }, 
        headers: {
            "Range" : "bytes="+byteRead+"-"
        }
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: This absolutely works for me. But the only problem I could see in console is ,some error messages when file stops growing. Is there any better way to handle this.                                                                                                       GET http://localhost:8080/GenNumber.txt 304 (Not Modified)
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ just.html:36

Comment: Is it an error? If the file has not been modified, so you do not have data to read.

Comment: in `url: "GenNumber.txt",` just replace `GenNumber.txt` by the correct url of the file

Comment: Error 304 is gone after adding cache : false to ajax but now I am getting error "416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)" when file stops growing. It seems browser is asking for some range and not getting it.

Comment: try to replace `byteRead` by `(byteRead-1)`

Comment: @sand that's ok, just catch the error and try again one second later